# Python Pandas style function to highlight specific columns under specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, styles

I am trying to write a function which compares two Data Frame column and highlight one column alone when the condition match.

For example as below: I have two column in a Data Frame ("C1","C2"). I want to iterate and compare each values in both the columns. If C1 > C2, highlight that value in C1. From below, (6 and 7) in C1 will be highlighted.

I got the below code from different place but it will be helpful if i can get a better solution.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [0,6,7], 'C2':[1,4,5]})
i = 0
def color_red(val):
    global i
    if not i > len(df['C1'])-1:
        color = 'red' if df['C1'][i] > df['C2'][i] else 'black'
        i+=1
    else:
        i = 0
        color = 'red' if df['C1'][i] > df['C2'][i] else 'black'
        i+=1
    return 'color: %s' % color
s = df.style.applymap(color_red,subset=['C1'])
s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) method with `axis=1` argument to apply your style row-wise:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [0,6,7], 'C2':[1,4,5]})

def color_red(s):
    color = 'color: red' if s.iloc[0] > s.iloc[1] else 'color: black'
    colors = [color] + [''] * (s.size - 1)
    return colors

s = df.style.apply(color_red, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for response!! Your code changes the font in C2 column also for 0 > 1. I want only C1 to be updated. Also, your code fails when we have other columns like C3,C4 along with C1 and C2 in the same data frame.

Comment: @premganesh Well, you did not mention there may be other columns in the data frame. I modified my answer to consider this case. Also I fixed the issue of change in the second column.